# Loading Level Scheme error

Tags: packages, levelscheme

I am new to *Mathematica*.
When I am using:

```
Get["LevelScheme`"];
```

it gives the following error:

> Get::noopen: "-- Message text not found -- (!(\"LevelScheme`LevelScheme`\"))"

Please help me with the above problem.

Thanks
Aditi

Comment: Did you `AppendTo` the path of the LevelScheme folder? `AppendTo[$Path,/path/goes/here/LevelScheme]`

Comment: Yes, before get command I have written another line: AppendTo[$Path, "C:\\Users\\Aditi\\Documents\\LevelScheme"]; where this C:\\Users\\Aditi\\Documents\\LevelScheme path is the place where I decompressed the ZIP file and it created a directory named LevelScheme with further sub directories.

Comment: So `C:/Users/Aditi/Documents/LevelScheme` is a folder which contains subfolders `BlockOptions`, `ClipToRectangle` etc. and also another `LevelScheme` folder?

Comment: Previously, it was giving error: $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 256 exceeded, 
so I added $RecursionLimit = Infinity and this error went away but it gave above error of levelscheme

Comment: Yes,  C:/Users/Aditi/Documents/LevelScheme is that folder which contains subfolders BlockOptions, ClipToRectangle etc. and also another LevelScheme folder

Comment: What do you get for `FileNames["LevelScheme",
"C:\\Users\\Aditi\\Documents\\LevelScheme", Infinity]`? There should only be two levels of `LevelScheme` folders, not three.

Comment: Yes there are two levels of LevelScheme folders only: 1 is the directory and another is the sub direcory.

Comment: and for FileNames command I get the following output: {"C:\\Users\\Aditi\\Documents\\LevelScheme\\LevelScheme"}

Comment: Did you try restarting the kernel, or Mathematica as a whole?

Comment: BTW, are you using Windows?

Comment: Yes I tried restarting mathematica. Yes I am using windows 8

Comment: and mathematica version 8 in windows

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I believe your $Path should include the directory  *containing* the Levelscheme directory, not the LevelScheme directory itself. So, that would be `AppendTo[$Path, "C:\\Users\\Aditi\\Documents]`

Comment: Yes i have tried with that also, but no change :(

Comment: @Aditiagarwal Marginally related, but LevelScheme is now replaced by [SciDraw](http://scidraw.nd.edu/).  If you don't *know* that you absolutely need the old LevelScheme, consider using SciDraw instead.  LevelScheme is no longer being developed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

Step 1) Run the command below to find your `Base` directory

```
 FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications"}]
```

In my case it was

```
"C:\\Users\\Username\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mathematica\\Applications"
```

Step 2) Copy all the folders inside the `LevelScheme` folder (this is crucial do not copy the main folder, only its contents are to copied) that you downloaded and paste it inside the directory that you found in step 1. In my case all the folders inside `LevelScheme` (the parent directory) are now inside `"C:\\Users\\Username\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mathematica\\Applications"`

Now you will be able to load the package